# Retrieve Taxonomy Label

Tags: taxonomy

I've gone through other posts here, but have been unsuccessful making this work

I think I need a push at the fundamental starting point for this, as I can't seem to convert the resulting output into its adjoining label.

When looking at a Taxonomy Term Archive page, I would like to display the Top Level Taxonomy Name above the output.

With the following code, if I have a Taxonomy 'Kitchen Features', slug 'kitchen-features' - and I am on a Term Archive for this Taxonomy (i.e. Dishwasher) this code will output 'kitchen-features'.  I need instead 'Kitchen Features'.

I thought I could achieve this with the addition of ->labels->name but evidently not applying it properly.  So below I am showing the code to the point of returning 'kitchen-features', what do I need to do with $taxonomy to reach the Label?  Thanks for any thoughts

```
private function get_taxonomy_by_term_id( $term_id ) {

    // We can't get a term if we don't have a term ID.
    if ( 0 === $term_id || null === $term_id ) {
        return;
    }

    // Grab the term using the ID then read the name from the associated taxonomy.
    $taxonomy = '';
    $term = get_term( $term_id );
    if ( false !== $term ) {
        $taxonomy = $term->taxonomy;
    }
    return trim( $taxonomy );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
private function get_taxonomy_by_term_id( $term_id ) {

    // We can't get a term if we don't have a term ID.
    if ( 0 === $term_id || null === $term_id ) {
        return;
    }

    // Grab the term using the ID then read the name from the associated taxonomy.
    $taxName = '';
    $term = get_term( $term_id );
    if ( false !== $term ) {
        $taxonomy = $term->taxonomy;
        $taxName = get_taxonomy($taxonomy)->labels->name

    }

    return trim( $taxName );
}
```

source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomy

Comment: Thanks, this works. I could see from pulling query vars that I needed to address another pull for this, but wasn't able to formulate it properly.  Appreciate the help.